# I don't understand how Java is pass by value

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

So I thought Java was pass by value but why does the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);

    phase1(numbers);

    for (Integer number: numbers) {
        System.out.println("number = " + number);
    }
}

static void phase1(List<Integer> numbers) {
    numbers.remove(0);
}
```

Print the following?

```
number = 2
number = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I thought Java was pass by value

It is.

> ...but why does the following code...print the following?

Because the *value* passed for reference types is the reference, not a copy of the object.

"Pass by reference" refers to a *completely different thing*, passing a reference to the *variable*. Java doesn't have that.

If Java had pass-by-reference, then this change to your method:

```
static void phase1(List<Integer> &numbers) {
// Pass-by-reference indicator --^--- that Java doesn't actually have
    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>()
}
```

...would make your code print no numbers at all. But it doesn't, so it doesn't.

Think of the object reference as an `int` or `long` that uniquely identifies the object elsewhere in memory. (Which is basically what it is.) Just as `a = b` with `int`s *copies* `b`'s value into `a`, so `a = b` *copies* `b`'s *value* into `a` even when the value is an object reference. The value being copied is the reference, not the object it refers to.

Comment: @QLiu: No worries. :-) BTW, swearing is a no-no on SO.

Comment: So I get that Java is pass by value where the value can be a reference, but internally how is that different than in C where you pass by reference with & internally?

Comment: @QLiu: C doesn't have pass-by-reference. C++ does. The difference is what the reference is to: In C++, if we have `foo(int &bar)` and we call it using `foo(x)`, inside `foo`, `bar` is a reference to the **variable** `x`. So `foo` can reach out and change the variable. That has nothing to do with object references, it's about *variable* references. Java doesn't have variable references.